# Is any alias equivalent to a function?

Tags: bash, alias

1. Is any alias equivalent to a function, in the sense that each appearance of the alias can be replaced with the function's name, and the function name in each call to the function can be replaced with the alias?
2. If I am correct, an arbitrary alias is defined in the following
   form:

   ```
   alias myalias=blahblah
   ```

   Is the alias defined in the above form always equivalent to a
   function defined as

   ```
   myfun () { blahblah $@ }
   ```

   ?

   If not, what function is the alias equivalent to?

Thanks.

Comment: Both that alias and function give me an error.

Comment: I would think the following are identical (or pretty much any one line command):
`alias test1="echo Hello"`
`test2(){ echo Hello ; }`

Comment: What is unclear about what I am asking? If you don't know it, would you rather leave the discussion open to others, than abuse your closing vote? Thanks.

Comment: As a fairly beginner *nix user a lot of your recent questions have been pretty confusing/unclear to me.  That being said I do not understand why people are downvoting them,  I have learned something from most of your questions and the answers to them and the lack of understanding is due to my knowledge of the subject not your question(s).

Comment: Thanks for your  kind word. @Jesse_b. I am  happier now, because I know there is at least one  who is open minded and capable of mutual understanding.

Comment: @Jesse_b Sorry, I misread your latest reply. My first comment was not meant for you, because you didn't close my post.

Comment: @Jesse_b, the [answers and comments here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4567/135943) may shed some light on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the fine manual tells us, aliases are almost completely superceded by functions. Functions can do pretty much anything an alias can do, and are capable of doing a lot more as they take arguments which can be used in arbitrary order.

The thing that functions can't do is prevent the expansion of their arguments. This means that the only reason for using an alias is to set up a function call without expansion.

```
alias funny='set -f; _funny'
_funny(){ set +f ; do_something_with_unexpanded_args ;}
```

and now you can run `funny *` and see the `*` rather than a list of the files in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

NO function is always equivalent to a given alias, since::

```
$ alias foo=bar
+ alias foo=bar
$ myfun () { bar "$@"; }
```

Now, let us use `foo` and `myfun` to define a function:

```
$ foo () { blah "$@"; }
$ myfun () { blah "$@"; }
```

What happens to `foo` and `myfun`?

```
$ type -a foo bar myfun
+ type -a foo bar myfun
foo is aliased to `bar'
bar is a function
bar ()
{
    blah "$@"
}
myfun is a function
myfun ()
{
    blah "$@"
}
```

Clearly, the function that was a supposed equivalent of the alias got redefined, but the alias was unaffected.

For most other cases, `myfun` would have been an equivalent to `foo`.

Comment: Thanks. You raised a very good point, definitely worth my upvote.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/383972/674