# Why does an alias work sometimes like a nameref and sometimes not?

Tags: bash, alias

I noticed an example from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/383825/674

```
$ alias foo=bar
$ foo () { blah "$@"; }
$ type -a foo bar  
foo is aliased to `bar'
bar is a function
bar ()
{
    blah "$@"
}
```

So redefining the alias `foo` actually redefines the aliased command `bar`. This works like a nameref, i.e. a variable with the reference attribute.

I experimented more with the following examples.

- Why does `mya=cat` not re-alias `mya` to `cat`, nor redefines the aliased `echo` to `cat`?
- Why does `mya () { cat test.sh; }`  redefine the aliased `echo` to the function, just like a nameref?

Thanks.

```
$ alias mya=echo
$ type mya
mya is aliased to `echo'
$ mya abc  # mya behaves exactly as echo
abc

$ mya=cat
$ type mya
mya is aliased to `echo'
$ mya test.sh # mya=cat doesn't alias mya to cat
test.sh


$ mya () { cat test.sh; }
$ type mya
mya is aliased to `echo'
$ mya  # Redefining mya as a function works, by outputing the content of test.sh
#! /usr/bin/env bash
echo $_
echo $0
$ echo # Redefining mya also redefines the aliased echo, just like a nameref
#! /usr/bin/env bash
echo $_
echo $0
```

Comment: `mya=cat` defines a variable, not an alias. You'd have to use `$mya` to access the variable's value.

Comment: And another data point for you: `alias foo=bar; function foo () { echo booh }` → The alias `foo` shadows the function `foo` (like it would for normal programs, see the ubiquitous `alias rm='rm -i'`), but as usual you can circumvent the alias by calling `\foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alias is expanded when it's the first word in the command. So when you type:

```
alias foo=bar
foo () { blah "$@"; }
```

the alias `foo` is expanded, so it's treated as if you'd typed:

```
bar () { blah "$@"; }
```

When you type:

```
alias mya=echo
mya=cat
```

the first word in the command is `mya=cat`, not just `mya`, so the alias is not expanded. `=` is not a word delimiter, it's merely the delimiter between the variable and value in a variable assignment.

Comment: Thanks.  How can i realias an existing alias to a different command, since assignment doesn't do the work?

Comment: Just do another `alias` command. `alias mya=cat`

Comment: Variable assignment is not subject to alias substitution, but this is not because the first word of the command is `mya=cat`. The first word of the command is what follows all variable assignments (in your example there is none). Therefore `mya=cat foo=bar mya ...` would execute `echo ...`

Comment: @xhienne True, that's another way to explain it. What I find somewhat confusing is that alias substitution is only supposed to happen in simple commands. Is a function definition a simple command? Yet it's happening there.

Comment: Each compound command is split in simple commands. Each first word of those simple commands is subject to alias substitution. A function is a compound command.